# Magento 2: Cache is not clearing. (All steps taken)

Tags: magento2, porto-theme

Changes on my site aren't showing up unless I load a previously unloaded product.

> I've tried removing pub/static admin and frontend
>
> I removed generated,
>   var/cache, and var/view_preprocessed

I cleaned and flushed the cache, used all 3 of the cache cleaning buttons in the lower corner (images, js, etc)

When I change something on the homepage (like the header type (porto theme))), it doesn't show up. It'll show up on a product I haven't opened before, but not the homepage or previously loaded products.

I ran

```
setup:upgrade, setup:di:compile, setup:statid-content:deploy -f
```

and I even tried reinstalling the theme and patches! No luck, even in private browsing with cookies cleared.

I tried restarting my server (cloudways) and that did it once, but only once.
I also keep getting console errors about require not being a function, but those come and go

I'm out of ideas. Is there anything I haven't tried yet?

Thanks

Comment: Varnish? CDN? Some super aggressive client side cache?

Comment: I worked with the server people (cloudways, managed hosting). They set things up so that the Varnish cache should clean whenever I clean the Magento cache. That's working for now

Comment: disable cache and then check changes are reflected or not?